# whats the significance of /dev/log/main and /dev/log/system in android logcat?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I usually get these two lines when i type `adb lolcat` in command line

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
D/dalvikvm( 2586): GC_CONCURRENT freed 651K, 7% free 12236K/13063K, paused 7ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm( 2586): GREF has increased to 201
W/AudioHardwareALSA( 2071): badstate and do recovery.....
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/ActivityManager( 2159): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList bnds=[909,207][1011,300]} from pid 2586
```

What is the significance of these two things in logcat output, anything important it signifies ?Thank You

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://elinux.org/Android_Logging_System says:

> The system log was created to keep system messages in a separate buffer (outside of '/dev/log/main') so that a single verbose application couldn't overrun system messages and cause them to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a log directly by write to /dev/log/main as below:

```
 $ printf "\5TagName\0Your Text Log\n" > /dev/log/main
```

the `\5` means `ANDROID_LOG_WARN` for other log level use these:

```
typedef enum android_LogPriority {
ANDROID_LOG_UNKNOWN = 0,
ANDROID_LOG_DEFAULT,    /* only for SetMinPriority() */
ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,
ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,
ANDROID_LOG_INFO,
ANDROID_LOG_WARN,
ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,
ANDROID_LOG_FATAL,
ANDROID_LOG_SILENT,     /* only for SetMinPriority(); must be last */
} android_LogPriority;
```

for more information see below source files [log](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/toolbox/log.c), [logd_write](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-2.1_r1/liblog/logd_write.c), [writev](https://chromium.googlesource.com/arc/arc/+/release-38.4410.120.0/mods/android/bionic/libc/arch-nacl/syscalls/writev.c), [logprint](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-2.1_r1/liblog/logprint.c) and [android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/)